# How to use binary search algorithm without index in Database

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I want to run this query

```
select * 
from table 
where column_1 = 12
```

I know how binary search working, maybe if I create an index on `column_1`, dbms will use the binary search.

The question here: how to use different algorithm in this case after creating index and is that applicable or not?

Comment: usually the optimizer attempts to generate the most optimal execution plan for a SQL statement. why would you change that?

Comment: sometimes, I just want to use binary search and don’t want to making more indexes, btw constraints and indexed will slow inserts because the cost of checking and maintaining those isn't free

Comment: Is there a really measurable performance degradation due to having an index in your system, or is this an attempt of a premature optimization? If there is an actual problem with index maintenance or overall query performance, you are better asking about that problem instead of in general. You said, that you understand binary search, which also includes the requirements to use a binary search. Now the question is if you have the data structure anywhere for binary search without an index?

Comment: No, I faced problems in insertion (was taking more time ) before, when we was making some constraints and indexes on tables so we was dropping those indexes before loading and after that building them.

Comment: This is a common approach in data warehouses and it is working fine as long as you are not dealing with real-time data. Don't touch it if it is working and satisfies the needs. Be also aware, that constraints also help the database engine to take decisions (e.g. when a foreign key is present and enforced, the engine knows, that certain joins would work in very predictable way and can take shortcuts), check constraints can help resolve where conditions in certain scenarios, etc. Of course maintaining these takes resources during CRUD operations

Comment: yes it is in a data warehouse project

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a declarative language, meaning, you define what you want to achieve, but the how it should be done is determined by the database engine.

In some cases/products you can force the behavior, but in general what algorithm is used to get the results is not controlled by the user.

Most database engines will try to get the desired results in the most optimal way, which is determined by the engine based on the information it has about the query and the underlaying data.

Indexes help the database engine to understand the data by providing information about possible values, their selectivity, etc, but at the end the database engine will make a decision if the index will be used or not.

Say, you have an index on a table which is storing the details of users. The index itself is on the column 'created_at' which is the time when the record was created.
Lets now say, that you started the business on 2019-09-01. Now if you have a query like this: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at > '2019-01-01'`, the database engine could use the index, but all records will match the where condition, therefore the engine will most probably decide to iterate on the clustered key, instead of using the index, because seeking the index, than doing a lookup for all records will need more resources than simply reading the entire table.
However if you execute the query with a different date, say 2021-09-01, the index most probably will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your clarifying for how the engine works